# Does a setter function's parameter name needs to be different from a private variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why does the constructor function return preset/initial value for this code?

I am calling the `setGear()` with a value of 5 yet `getGear()` returns 1 instead of 5.

This can be fixed by changing the parameter name in the `setGear()` function to anything other than 'gear'.

```
var Bike = function() {
     var gear = 1;

     this.getGear = function() {
         return gear;
     };

     this.setGear = function(gear) {
         gear = gear;
     };
 };

 ////////
 var myBike = new Bike();
 myBike.setGear(5);
 result = myBike.getGear();
```

Comment: You shadowed the `var gear` with the function parameter `gear`, so `gear = gear` mutates the "nearest" identifier.

Comment: FYI, linters can catch these kinds of errors if you configure them to disallow shadowing, which IMO, isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using same variable name gear in your set Gear method.
when you call the function setGear(**gear**), **gear** will take the value of local variable gear defined in the Bike function.

change the variable name to something different for example input

```js
var Bike = function() {
     var gear = 1;

     this.getGear = function() {
         return gear;
     };

     this.setGear = function(input) {
         gear = input;
     };
 };

 ////////
 var myBike = new Bike();
 myBike.setGear(5);
 result = myBike.getGear();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A parameter name is a local symbol in the function. It hides any variables with the same name in outer scopes. In the `.getGear()` function, the symbol `gear` refers to the variable declared in the constructor function. However, because `.setGear()` has a parameter *also* named `gear`, that outer `gear` is not accessible.

If you think about it, in that assignment:

```
gear = gear;
```

it would be pretty bizarre if one `gear` were one thing while the other was something else.

Comment: meaning in the setGear function the private variable gear (initially set to 1) is never assigned a value and rather the function parameter gear is updated to 5 whereas getGear always accesses the private variable resulting in a return value of 1 instead of 5. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

with `gear = gear` you are assigning the value to the parameter 'gear' not the class member. To avoid confusion, simply rename your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Bike = function() {
 var gear;
 this.gear = 1;

 this.getGear = function() {
     return this.gear;
 };

 this.setGear = function(gear) {
     this.gear = gear;
 };
};
////////
var myBike = new Bike();
myBike.setGear(5);
result = myBike.getGear();
```

Use this keyword to access gear variable

Comment: That alters the meaning of the code so that `gear` is now mutable via direct object reference instead of access being controlled by the functions.